# Error for using for-loop when producing simulations

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to use for loop to **simulate** 1,000 portfolios with 3 bonds in each portfolio, and finding the probability that two out of three bonds default.
Here's my code (with comments):

```
#Reproducibility
set.seed(33)
#Number of trials
n<-1000
#Initialize variables
numberofdefaults<-0
counter<-0
portfolio <- 0
for (i in 1:n){
  portfolio[i] <- rbinom(3, 1, prob = 0.127)      # generate three random binomial deviates with probabiltiy of sucess("default" in my case)0.127 and store them in a vector 
  numberofdefaults[i] <- sum(portfolio[i] == 1)      # find the number of defaults in the vector (1 for default) and add them up 
    if (numberofdefaults[i] == 2) {              # if number of defaults is 2, then add 1 to the counter
        counter<-counter+1
    }
}
```

When I execute the code, I keep getting an error message: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Thnx so much for taking your time. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working as intended. Portfolio is a vector, so when you run rbinom(), which has 3 elements, you are attempting to cram 3 elements into one element (the ith element of that particular for loop). It gives you a warning that it can't do that (and only stores in the first element each time). Instead you want Portfolio to be a list.

```
set.seed(33)
#Number of trials
n<-1000
#Initialize variables
numberofdefaults<-0
counter<-0
portfolio <- list() # Change this
for (i in 1:n){
  portfolio[[i]] <- rbinom(3, 1, prob = 0.127)      # Change this 
  numberofdefaults[i] <- sum(portfolio[[i]] == 1)      # Change this
  if (numberofdefaults[i] == 2) {              
    counter<-counter+1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnx so much. Much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to investigate if `sum(portfolio[[i]] == 1) ` is doing what you want it to do. I'm not clear on what is the expected behaviour. Otherwise, please mark the answer as solving the problem.

Comment: Understood. Thnx for the help.